# "Все равно на"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Меня жутко раздражает, когда говорят/пишут "все равно на", например "все равно на меня". Я всегда считала, что "все равно" может быть только просто, это "наплевать" может быть "на". Но все так говорят, иногда даже по телевизору, и телевизионные редакторы их не исправляют. Неужели, я не права и можно говорить "все равно на (что-то)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя так говорить, Вы правы. Фраза неграмотная. Выражение ВСЁ РАВНО не сочетается с существительными и местоимениями с предлогом НА.